# How to fix the influence from PC sceen scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html i set `border:2px solid red` to `#my_div`, but In the developer mode of chrome, it shows like the border got cut to `1.867`

[image: the css]
[image: the change of border-width]

I searched similar question and now I know the border-width is effected by my pc screen setting which is 125% bigger. But i still don't know how to fix it.

Could i get the scaling persent of user's screen setting?
Could i make the chrome not change my border-width? 
Or any other way to fix it?

Any suggestion is welcome and thank you !